# puppet: merging lists of hashes?

Tags: puppet

If I have a puppet class that receives a hash variable, and I want to provide defaults for some of the keys in the hash variable, I can simply use a hash merge (`$hash1 + $hash2`) to generate a new class with the desired defaults.  I.e, given:

```
defaults:
  field1: default1
  field2: default2
  field3: defaul3

myconfig:
  field1: val1
  field3: val3
```

Then `$defaults + $myconfig` gives me:

```
finalconfig:
  field1: val1
  field2: default2
  field3: val3
```

But what do I do if I  want to accomplish the same thing with a *list* of hashes?  That is, if my input is:

```
myconfig:
  - field1: custom1
    field2: custom2
  - field1: custom1
    field3: custom3
```

And I have defaults that look like:

```
defaults:
  field1: default1
  field2: default2
  field3: default3
```

I want to end up with:

```
finalconfig:
  - field1: custom1
    field2: custom2
    field3: default3
  - field1: custom1
    field2: default2
    field3: custom3
```

Is there a way to do this within a puppet manifest?

Comment: Presumably you will iterate over the list at some point. As part of that iteration can you merge the hashes there?

Comment: Also, are you running a version a puppet with sane iteration (e.g. "each")? Otherwise you're going to have to use a defined type.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be easier than I thought.  If I have:

```
$defaults = {
  field1 => default1,
  field2 => default2,
  field3 => default3
}
```

I can apply those defaults to a *list* of hashes like this

```
$finalconfig = $config.map |cfg| {
  $defaults + $cfg
}
```